# ClearQuest data migration to JIRA

Tags: clearquest

We plan on migrating from ClearQuest to JIRA.
Does anyone have experience migrating the data (exporting from CQ and importing to JIRA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be interested in the future. I have found the following:

[JIRA - Migrating from Other Issue Trackers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Migrating+from+Other+Issue+Trackers)

[JIRA Cookbook - Migration off IBM Rational ClearQuest](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/JIRA+Cookbook+-+Migration+off+IBM+Rational+ClearQuest)

I hope this helps someone...